# The form of the measure defined on the power set of all natural numbers

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Can anybody give the details of the second part of the following question?

${\bf Question.}$ Let $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ be the family of all subsets of natural numbers. Given a sequence $\{\alpha_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of real numbers, let $\mu:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\longrightarrow [0,\infty]$ defined by

${\hspace{2cm}}\mu(\emptyset)=0$ and $\displaystyle\mu(S)=\sum_{n\in S}\alpha_n  \ \ \text{if} \ \ S\neq\emptyset.{\hspace{2cm}}$ (*)

Then it is easy to show that $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. (This was the first part of the problem). But how one can prove that:

Each measure on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is of the form given in (*) above for some suitable sequence $\{\alpha_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset[0,\infty]$.

Comment: Well, measures are (countably) additive, so define $\alpha_i=\mu(\{i\})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mu$ is any measure on $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, you can easily prove that $$\mu(S) = \sum_{n\in S}\mu(\{n\})$$

Can you do the last step yourself?

Comment: If $S\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, then $\displaystyle S=\bigcup_{s\in S}\{s\}$ ? Isn't that?

Comment: @serenus Yes, that's true. But you have to tell what $\alpha_n$ need to be.

Comment: $\mu(\{s\})=:\alpha_s$ for each $s\in \mathbb{N}$, is it okay?

Comment: @serenus Looks good.